# a library that provides a view like the incoming call in phone app?

Tags: android, view

I'm searching for a library that provides something like this: [image]

the button that you can drag to get the option you want.

I found [GlowPadView](https://github.com/frakbot/GlowPadBackport) but from what I understand it is risky to use it beacause it might break in future releases (or maybe even broken right now)

Does anybody know of a library I can use?

Comment: This might work but I'm not sure if it can be implemented properly. https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/lockscreen-create-your-own-lockscreen-with-just-5-lines-of-code.43327/

Comment: This doesn't seem to be for java sadly